# javascript function passes only one specific parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I built this function in my html page:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function set() {
        var type = 'test';
        var status = 0;
        var id = 2;
        $.post("sys/class/buttonHandler.php"), { status: status};
    }
</script>
```

that is triggered by this button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="set()" class="btn">Press here</button>
```

to reach this buttonHandler.php:

```
<?php

    require 'class.global.php';

    $type = 'test';
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $id = 2;

    set($type, $status, $id);

?>
```

that correctly executes this function in the class.global.php:

```
function set($type, $status, $id)
{
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET $type = '$status' WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

The problem is when I try to change the parameter that the javascript function passes or when I try to add the other two parameters, like this:

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
                function set_profile() {
                    var type = 'test';
                    var status = 0;
                    var id = 2;
                    $.post("sys/class/admobButtonHandler.php"), { status: status, type: type, id: id};
                }
            </script>

<?php

require 'class.global.php';

$type = $_POST['type'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

setProfile($type, $status, $id);

?>
```

Nothing works anymore..
Is there any other way that I can make this work?
Thanks

Comment: You are missing a `)` at the end of your `$.post()` function, is this a mistake?

Comment: yes it was..thank you

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the jQuery docs for the post() function. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/. You've got your syntax all wrong... It should be:

```
$.post("/sys/class/admobButtonHandler.php", {status: status, type: type, id: id});
```